# Identify user by email only trigger feedback survey after reloading page

Tags: hubspot

I created a landing page where I wish to show HubSpot feedback survey(NPS).

I already know my customer email, so, I follow this docs to identify my customer https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/events/tracking-code#identify-a-visitor.

Problem is, if I open my landing page for the first time in a browser without hubspot cookies, it does not works. I need to refresh the page to show NPS survey.

Because it is a landing page, I need it to works straight way, for the first access.

I'm using this code to identify my customer:

```
<script>
    var _hsq = window._hsq = window._hsq || [];
    _hsq.push(["identify",{
        email: 'my@email.com',
    }]);
  </script>

  <!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/XXXXXXX.js"></script>
```

I know this code works because when I run it for the first time, it tracks a page view to the customer I identify, but the survey do not shows up.